# Waiting for a Bus, arrives every 10 minutes on average

Tags: probability

What is the probability of waiting for a bus at most 30 minutes when on average a bus arrives every 10 minutes

Comment: Could be a probability of $1$, depending on the distribution in question, but it is undecidable without giving us more information.

Comment: Do bus arrivals form a homogeneous Poisson process?  If, on the other hand, the buses stick closely to a regular schedule, the probability could be $1$.

Comment: does it change the problem if wait time is exactly 30

Comment: This is a classic case of a Poisson Distribution.

Comment: Can you explain

Comment: The probability can be 1 for example if the buses unfailingly follow the schedule that they come in pairs at 20 minute intervals. Or, more simply, if they follow a tight schedule of 1 bus every 10 minutes. It can also be 1/2 if a group of six buses shows up once per hour. None of these are likely to occur in practice, but to make a meaningful question you need to specify a model.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The busses don't need to 'stick _closely_ to a regular schedule' for the probability to equal $1$. They just need to deviate not more then $\pm 10$ minutes from a regular 10-minutes schedule to keep any interval not exceeding 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In Statistics, the number of buses arriving in a time-interval of length $t$ is usually modeled by the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$ (Assuming the buses arrive at homogeneous Poisson process, as mentioned by @Robert Israel in a comment above. This is the usual assumption that we make). $\lambda$ denotes the rate of arrival of buses in unit interval of time. Since, on average, the buses arrive every 10 minutes, $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$.

Let $X$ denote the number of buses arriving in the time-interval, say $(0,t)$, and $T$ denote the waiting time until the first bus arrives. The crucial observation here is that $$\{X=0\} \iff \{T>t\}$$

Now the probability mass function of Poisson distribution (with parameter $\lambda t$) is given by:
$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^x}{x!}$$
where $x!=1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times x$. Since $X$ follows poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$, we have
$$P(T>t)=P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda t}$$
In this problem $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$ and we are required to calculate $P(T \leq 30)$.
$$P(T \leq 30)=1-P(T>30)=1-e^{-(\frac{1}{10} \times 30)}=1-e^{-3} \approx 0.9502$$
This is the exact expression, which is close to $1$, but slightly less.